# Adding a gtksourceview custom language with no root access

Tags: gedit, gtksourceview

I'm trying to add a new gtksourceview custom language for use with gedit, but I don't have root access nor sudo privileges to change the /usr/<...> directory.

Is there any alternative?

Our system administrator is reluctant to change /usr/<...>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had overlooked the solution [Language Definition v2.0 Reference](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-reference.html) :

Custom user languages are usually placed in **~/.local**/share/gtksourceview-4/language-specs/. Note: replace 4 with 2.0 or 3.0 in the path for GtkSourceView version 2 or version 3.

Comment: The link above points to developer-old.gnome.org, i.e., to a deprecated documentation site. A newer link to the GtkSourceView Language Definition Reference is: https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtksourceview/gtksourceview5/lang-reference.html